# Add Autoplay in Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one Image-slider but I can't make it auto-play.

Here my screen looks...

[image]

In this section Left & Right button. on click on that button, it's work fine, Image rotate perfect.

But I need auto-play in this slider..

*Please Help.*

**My Script in HEAD section is...**

```
<script>
$(function () 
{
    $('#cbp-fwslider').cbpFWSlider();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) 
{
    $(".royalSlider").royalSlider
    ({
        autoScaleSlider: true,
        autoPlay: 
        {
            enabled: true,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            delay: 300
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**My HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="royalSlider">
        <div id="cbp-fwslider" class="cbp-fwslider">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="img04" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

IF YOU NEED ANY KIND OF CODE TO UNDERSTAND MORE PLEASE TELL ME.
PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Could you provide us a link to the plugin you're using?, possible a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Sorry, but can you please explain what is plugin..?
Plugins means .js file?

Comment: In your browser click F12 and go to Console. Please, write here if have any javascript error.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: No Error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two different slider plugins? `cbpFWSlider()` and `royalSlider()`; make sure that they are not conflicting.